# Can not create drop down list

Tags: jquery, spring, select, drop-down-menu, spring-jdbc

I have to make Relational mapping  between products and brands
and show it in html

**Entity Class Brand**

```
         package com.eazytek.Entity;
        
        import lombok.*;
        
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        
        import javax.persistence.*;
        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Set;
        
        @Entity
        @ToString
        @Data
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @Setter
        @Getter
        @EqualsAndHashCode
        @Table(name = "brand")
        public class Brand implements Serializable {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "b_Id")
            private int b_Id;
        
            @Column(name = "b_Name")
            private String b_Name;
        
            @Column(name = "b_Origin")
            private String b_Origin;
        
        
        }
```

**Entity Class Product**

```
       package com.eazytek.Entity;
        
        
        import lombok.*;
        
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        
        @ToString
        @Data
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Entity
        public class Product {
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        
            private int pr_Id;
            private String pr_Name;
            private String pr_Type;
        
        }
```

**Brand Repository**

```
        package com.eazytek.Repository;
        
        import com.eazytek.Entity.Brand;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
        
        
        public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, 
        Integer> {
     
        }
```

**Product Repository**

```
    package com.eazytek.Repository;

    import com.eazytek.Entity.Product;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    

    public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, 
     Integer> {
    }
```

**Product Service Class**

```
    package com.eazytek.Service;


    import com.eazytek.Entity.Product;
    import com.eazytek.Repository.ProductRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Service
     public class ProoductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository prods;

    public List<Product> listAll() {
        return prods.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Product product) {
        prods.save(product);
    }

    public Product get(int pr_Id) {
        return prods.findById(pr_Id).get();
    }

    public void delete(int pr_Id) {
        prods.deleteById(pr_Id);


    }
    }
```

**Brand Service Class**

```
        package com.eazytek.Service;
        
        import com.eazytek.Entity.Brand;
        import com.eazytek.Repository.BrandRepository;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
        
        import java.util.List;
        
        @Service
        public class Brandservice {
    
    
        @Autowired
        private BrandRepository repository;
    
        public List<Brand> listAll() {
            return repository.findAll();
        }
    
        public void save(Brand brand) {
            repository.save(brand);
        }
    
        public Brand get(int b_Id) {
            return repository.findById(b_Id).get();
        }
    
        public void delete(int b_Id) {
            repository.deleteById(b_Id);
    
    
        }
        }
```

**Product Model View**

```
    package com.eazytek.ModelView;
    import com.eazytek.Entity.Product;
    import lombok.Data;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    @Data
    public class ProductModelView {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int pr_Id;
    private String pr_Name;
    private String pr_Type;



     public static ProductModelView ToProductModelView(Product product) {
    ProductModelView productModelView = new ProductModelView();
    if (product.getPr_Id() >= 0) {
        productModelView.setPr_Id(product.getPr_Id());
    }
    productModelView.setPr_Name(product.getPr_Name());
    productModelView.setPr_Type(product.getPr_Type());

    return productModelView;
    }

     public static Product ToProductModelView(ProductModelView 
    productModelView) {

    Product product = new Product();

    if (productModelView.getPr_Id() >= 0) {
        product.setPr_Id(productModelView.getPr_Id());
    }
    productModelView.setPr_Name(product.getPr_Name());
    productModelView.setPr_Type(product.getPr_Type());
    return product;
     }

     public static List<ProductModelView> ToProductModelView(List<Product> 
     productList) {

    List<ProductModelView> productModelViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product product : productList) {
        ProductModelView productModelView = new ProductModelView();
        productModelView.setPr_Id(product.getPr_Id());
        productModelView.setPr_Name(product.getPr_Name());
        productModelView.setPr_Type(product.getPr_Type());
        productModelView.setPr_Id(product.getPr_Id());

    }
    return productModelViewList;
      }


        }
```

**Brand Model View**

```
     package com.eazytek.ModelView;
     import com.eazytek.Entity.Brand;
    import lombok.Data;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    
    @Data
    public class BrandModelView {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int b_Id;
        private String b_Name;
        private String b_Origin;
    
        public static BrandModelView ToBrandModelView(Brand brand) {
            BrandModelView brandModelView = new BrandModelView();
            if (brand.getB_Id() >= 0) {
                brandModelView.setB_Id(brand.getB_Id());
            }
            brandModelView.setB_Name(brand.getB_Name());
            brandModelView.setB_Origin(brand.getB_Origin());
    
    
            return brandModelView;
        }
    
        public static Brand ToBrandsModelXview(BrandModelView 
            brandModelView) {
    
            Brand brand = new Brand();
    
            if (brandModelView.getB_Id() >= 0) {
                brand.setB_Id(brandModelView.getB_Id());
            }
            brand.setB_Origin(brandModelView.getB_Origin());
            brand.setB_Name(brandModelView.getB_Name());
    
    
            return brand;
        }
    
        public static List<BrandModelView> ToBrandModelYview(List<Brand> 
            brandList) {
    
            List<BrandModelView> brandModelViewList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Brand brand : brandList) {
                BrandModelView brandModelView = new BrandModelView();
                brandModelView.setB_Id(brand.getB_Id());
                brandModelView.setB_Origin(brand.getB_Origin());
            }
            return brandModelViewList;
        }
    
        private ModelAndView getModelAndView(BrandModelView 
                  brandModelView) {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("brand_add");
            modelAndView.addObject("brandModelView", brandModelView);
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
```

**Product Controller**

```
               package com.eazytek.Controller;
        import com.eazytek.Entity.Product;
        import com.eazytek.ModelView.ProductModelView;
        import com.eazytek.Service.ProoductService;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.ui.Model;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

        import java.util.List;

        @Controller
        public class ProductController {

          @Autowired

          private ProoductService prooductService;


            @RequestMapping("/product")
            public String viewProductHome(Model model) {
          List<Product> productList = prooductService.listAll();
          model.addAttribute("productList", productList);

        return "product_index";
      }

       private ModelAndView getModelAndView(ProductModelView 
         productModelView) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("product_add");
        modelAndView.addObject("productModelView", productModelView);
        return modelAndView;
    }


        private ModelAndView ToProductModelView(ProductModelView 
        productModelView) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("product_add");
        modelAndView.addObject("productModelView", productModelView);
        return modelAndView;
    }

        @RequestMapping("/new_product")
        public String shoeNewBrandFrom(Model model) {
        Product product = new Product();
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        return "product_add";

    }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/save_product", method = 
        RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveProductPage(@ModelAttribute("product") Product 
            product) {
            prooductService.save(product);


        return "redirect:/product";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/edit_product/{pr_Id}")
    public ModelAndView showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "pr_Id") 
        int pr_Id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("product_edit");
        Product product = prooductService.get(pr_Id);
        mav.addObject("product", product);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete_product/{pr_Id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "pr_Id") int pr_Id) {
        prooductService.delete(pr_Id);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }


}
```

**Brand Controller**

```
    package com.eazytek.Controller;
    import com.eazytek.Entity.Brand;
    import com.eazytek.ModelView.BrandModelView;
    import com.eazytek.Service.Brandservice;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import java.util.List;
    
    @Controller
    
    public class BrandController {


    @Autowired
    private Brandservice service;
    private Brand brand;


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewProductPage(Model model) {
        List<Brand> brandList = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("brandList", brandList);
        return "index";
    }

    private ModelAndView getModelAndView(BrandModelView brandModelView) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("brand_add");
        modelAndView.addObject("brandModelView", brandModelView);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/new_brand")
    public String shoeNewBrandFrom(Model model) {
        Brand brand = new Brand();
        model.addAttribute("brand", brand);
        return "index_add";

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/save_brand", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveBrandxPage(@ModelAttribute("brand") Brand brand) {
        service.save(brand);


        return "redirect:/";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/edit_brand/{b_Id}")
    public ModelAndView showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "b_Id") 
         int 
        b_Id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index_edit");
        Brand brand = service.get(b_Id);
        mav.addObject("brand", brand);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete_brand/{b_Id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "b_Id") int b_Id) {
        service.delete(b_Id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }


    }
```

**Html Views Entry point**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>

        <title>Document</title>
        <title>Product Manager</title>
    </head>
        <body style="background-color: bisque">
        <div align="center">
            <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb- 
                  3">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 id="header-title">One to Many <span 
            style="display:none">123</span></h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
        <div id="main" class="card card-body">
            <h1 style="color:green    ">Store Manager Admin</h1>
            <h2 style="color:green">Store View</h2>
            <h1>Product Resource</h1>
            <a href="/new_brand">Add Brand to Shop </a>
            <a href="/product">Add Product to store </a>
            <a href="/">To_Home</a>
            <br/><br/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
            <table border="1" width="82%" align="center" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Brand ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Origin</th>

                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="brand : ${brandList }">

                <td th:text="${brand.b_Id}">Brand ID</td>
                <td th:text="${brand.b_Name}">Name</td>
                <td th:text="${brand.b_Origin}">Origin</td>

                <td>

                    <a th:href="@{'/edit_brand/' + 
                   ${brand.b_Id}}">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a th:href="@{'/delete_brand/' + 
                ${brand.b_Id}}">Delete</a>>
                    <a th:href="@{'/Sales/' + ${brand.b_Id}}">Shop</a>

                </td>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>

                              </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                </div>

                </body>
                </html>

       **Html page To Add a brand to the table and MySql**

        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>

        <title>Document</title>
        <title>Product Manager</title>
    </head>
        <body style="background-color: bisque">
        <div align="center">
            <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb- 
                    3">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 id="header-title">One to Many <span 
           style="display:none">123</span></h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
        <div id="main" class="card card-body">
            <h1 style="color:green    ">Store Manager Admin</h1>
            <h2 style="color:green">Store View</h2>
            <h1>Product Resource</h1>
            <a href="/new_brand">Add Brand to Shop </a>
            <a href="/product">Add Product to store </a>
            <a href="/">To_Home</a>
            <br/><br/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
            <table border="1" width="82%" align="center" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Brand ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Origin</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="brand : ${brandList }">

                <td th:text="${brand.b_Id}">Brand ID</td>
                <td th:text="${brand.b_Name}">Name</td>
                <td th:text="${brand.b_Origin}">Origin</td>

                <td>

                    <a th:href="@{'/edit_brand/' + 
                  ${brand.b_Id}}">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a th:href="@{'/delete_brand/' + 
              ${brand.b_Id}}">Delete</a>>
                    <a th:href="@{'/Sales/' + ${brand.b_Id}}">Shop</a>

                </td>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>

                              </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                </div>

                </body>
                </html>

    **Html Page to Edit the Data On the Brand Table**
            <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
                  scale=1.0">
           
        
            <title>Document</title>
            <title>Product Manager</title>
        
        
        </head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Create New Product</title>
        </head>
        <body background="">
        <div align="center">
            <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb- 
             3">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 id="header-title">One to Many <span 
                 style="display:none">123</span></h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <h1>Create New Product</h1>
            <br/>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/save_brand}" 
             th:object="${brand}"
                  method="post">
        
                <table border="0" cellpadding="12">
        
        
                    <tr>
                        <td>Brand Id:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{b_Id}"/></td>
                    </tr>
        
        
                    <tr>
                        <td> Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{b_Name}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Origin:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{b_Origin}"/> 
                     </td>
                    </tr>
        
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**Html Page Display of product **

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
                  scale=1.0">

            <title>Document</title>
            <title>Product Manager</title>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color: bisque">
        <div align="center">
            <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb- 
                     3">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 id="header-title">One to Many <span 
                       style="display:none">123</span></h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="main" class="card card-body">
        
                    <h1 style="color:green    ">Store Manager </h1>
                    <h2 style="color:green">Store View</h2>
                    <h1>Product Resource</h1>
                    <a href="/new_product">Add Product To Store </a>
                    <a href="/">To_Home</a>
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <table border="1" width="82%" align="center" 
                         cellpadding="5">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="product : ${ productList}">
                        <td th:text="${product.pr_Id}">Product ID</td>
                        <td th:text="${product.getPr_Name()}">Name</td>
                        <td th:text="${product.pr_Type}">Type</td>
                        <td>
                            <a th:href="@{'/edit_product/' + 
                   ${product.pr_Id}}">Edit</a>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
                          th:href="@{'/delete_product/' + 
                                  ${product.pr_Id}}">Delete</a>>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
                                         th:href="@{'/sell_product/' +                                       
                                         ${product.pr_Id}}">Sell</a>>
        
        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

**html page to Add a new Brand to the brand table**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>                                    
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>


            <title>Document</title>
            <title>Product Manager</title>


        </head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Create New Product</title>
        </head>
        <body background="">
        <div align="center">
            <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb- 
              3">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 id="header-title">One to Many <span
                            style="display:none">123</span></h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <h1>Create New Product</h1>
            <br/>
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/save_brand}" 
                  th:object="${brand}"
                  method="post">

                <table border="0" cellpadding="12">


                    <tr>
                        <td>Brand Id:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{b_Id}"/></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td> Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{b_Name}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Origin:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{b_Origin}"/> 
                 </td>
                    </tr>

                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </td>


                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the dropdown list (**select**) element.
Also, can you tell me, how do you request the data?

You will need to go through each one and create **option** elements.

```js
function appendOpt(text) {
var e = document.createElement("option");
e.innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById(/*the id of the select element*/).append(e);
}
var list = [/*retrieved data*/];
list.forEach(e => appendOpt(e));
```

Hope this helped a bit!

Comment: Like you can see in my question there are tables but no select tags I dont Know jquery and can no do this task am learning though Help me out if you can it has been a month that I got this assignment